# How safe is PassportJS out of the box?

Tags: authentication, node.js

If I have an NodeJS server (an express server) that requires a user to log in before rendering files, how safe is PassportJS to use out-of-the-box?

Currently I am using it with express-session middleware for express and serving everything over HTTPS. User passwords are hashed with bcrypt and the hash is stored in the user database. I am using `req.isAuthenticated` on all incoming requests to ensure the user is authenticated before serving the secure pages.

Is it advisable to use any other libraries to make this system secure?

Answer (score 3):

Passport.js out of the box is safe as your implementation of it to protect routes from unauthorized access. For example if you forget to apply the middleware to certain routes they would not be protected, if you make a mistake in configuring the authentication strategy you may open up your application to an attack. It is important that you heavily test you code for potential security issues as well as have code review from your co-workers to avoid your own personal bias.

Answer (score 0):

Passport.js’s default configuration should be as safe as other standard software, except that it is [vulnerable to session fixation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/192) (this is actually a [limitation of `express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/425)). Hopefully, if this changes, either Passport.js will be fixed or it will no longer be considered a standard authentication framework.

But to definitively answer this question, we need to understand your threat model: what threats are you concerned about, and what costs are you prepare to incur to defend against them?